I2C TCA9548a Can't Reach Slave Device
I recently finally got my PCB back for an I2C MUX board I built. The board has 4 TCA9548a MUXs that connect to their slave devices via screw terminals. I want to talk to embedded boards that all have the same address of 0x08. I have attached a picture of my schematic below. Currently I am using a raspberry pi for the master device. I tried running my code but got an error when I tried to open up a channel on the MUX (I used the Adafruit tca9548a library). Anyone have any suggestions or see blatant errors that I am not seeing? I used the raspberry pi command "i2cdetect -y 1" and my MUXs can all be seen with their correct addresses (I only have 1 connected to the board right now). The breakout board comes with a 10k pullup resistor for the MUX. I also attached the schem from the TCA9548A datasheet too. Here is my current code:
import adafruit_tca9548a
import time
import board

# Create the I2C Bus
i2c = board.I2C()

# Create the 4 MUXs and give them to the I2C bus
TCA1 = adafruit_tca9548a.TCA9548A(i2c)
# This repeats 3 more times for MUXs TCA2, TCA3, and TCA4 and then they end with (i2c, their address) but I took that out until I get the 1st MUX working.

# Print the MUX addresses for the user to see so they know which MUX adddress to use when they are writing to or reading from a slave device connected to one of those MUXs
print("The MUX addresses are given below:")
print("Mux 1 = 0x70")
print("Mux 2 = 0x71")
print("Mux 3 = 0x72")
print("Mux 4 = 0x73")                    

print("The channels for each MUX are as follows:")
print("Channel 0 = 0")
print("Channel 1 = 1")
print("Channel 2 = 2")
print("Channel 3 = 3")
print("Channel 4 = 4")
print("Channel 5 = 5")
print("Channel 6 = 6")
print("Channel 7 = 7")

# Go through MUX 1
# Decide wether user wants to write to or read from a device connected to the MUX, if neither, pass on to next MUX or complete all transactions then pass on to MUX 2

while True:
print("Mux 1, address 0x70")
action = input("Select the channel the device you which to address if connected to, or 'c' to go to next MUX:") # Select a channel on MUX1 that your target device is connected to

# If Channel 0 is selected for MUX 1
    if action == '0':   # If '0' is inputted, target the device on channel 0 MUX 1
        TCA1[0].try_lock()  # Enable channel 0 MUX 1
        try:
            action = input("Do you want to write to or read from the slave device? (w/r): "). lower()   # Ask user to choose between writng to or reading from the device
            if action == 'w':   # If user selects 'w' proceed with write to protocols
                SlavAddr = input("Input the address of the slave device:")  # User inputs the slave's address which is stored in SlavAddr
                n = int(input("Input the desired length of the read function:"))    # User inputs the length of the read function byte array
                wbuffer = bytearray(n) # Set up the byte array with the length that the user selects
                TCA1[0].readfrom_into(SlavAddr, wbuffer)  # Function to get the read from the requested MUX, Channel, and device
                result = wbuffer
                TCA1[0].writeto(SlavAddr, wbuffer)    # The slave address and the buffer are sent to the opened channel, MUX address and channel pre-inputted
                print("")
            elif action == 'r': # If user selects 'r' proceed with read from protocols
                SlavAddr = input("Input the address of the slave device:")  # User inputs the slave's address which is stored in SlavAddr
                n = int(input("Input the desired length of the read function:"))    # User inputs the length of the read function byte array
                rbuffer = bytearray(n) # Set up the byte array with the length that the user selects
                TCA1[0].readfrom_into(SlavAddr, rbuffer)  # Function to get the read from the requested MUX, Channel, and device
                result = rbuffer
                print(result)   # Read the result of the read function
                print("")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Input, enter either 'w' or 'r'.")    # Error message that write to or read from command was incorrect
            pass
        TCA1[0].unlock()    # Disable the channel and continue to next part of the loop
# This repeats for the remaining 7 channels using elif, then there are 3 more while loops with the same formatting that follow for the other 3 MUXs.





OK, so what error you got? On which line? And I can't understand your schematics to verify if the muxes are used correctly. What voltage is used for pull-ups and mux supply?

The error I am getting comes after I select the channel, I am getting an error on line that says "TCA1[0].try_lock() #Enable channel 0 MUX 1" which would be line 38, and the error also says "OSError: (Errno 5) Input/output error". I am using the raspberry pi's 3.3v supply for the MUX and the pull-ups. I am using a two-page schematic from kicad. The first picture shows the power supply connecting to the MUX and the second picture shows the MUX connecting to the slave devices via the pull up resistors (10k each).

At least you could try writing to the chip at 0x70 directly. The point is that the first thing that ever tries to communicate with the chip is the method try_lock so if it can't then nothing can.

Ok, I'll try that thank you
